# Adjust collectionView.scrollToItem to consider inset?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm sometimes scroll to the left of a cell like this:

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(
    at: IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0),
    at: .left, // TODO: Left ignores inset
    animated: true
)
```

This is how it starts out before `scrollToItem` implemented:

[image]

However, when I try to use scroll to item, it sticks the cell to the edge instead of considering the inset:

[image]

Is there an easy way to fix `collectionView.scrollToItem` to accommodate the insets?

Comment: try **.bottom** from **.left**

Comment: Good idea, but didn't work for me unfortunately. I tried: "collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [.bottom, .left], animated: true)". I also tried difference variations like [.top, .left], .bottom, .top, [.left, .bottom], etc.

Comment: 1. Is it Vertical Or Horizontal in Direction?
2. What is the size of your cell? e.g. One Item is being displayed at a time or two items or n number

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the regular method `collectionView.scrollToItem` if you set your inset in `collectionView.contentInset` instead of `layout.sectionInset`.

Answer (score 7):

Objective-C

```
   /**
     Assumptions:
     1. Your collection view scrolls horizontally
     2. You are using UICollectionViewFlowLayout to layout you collection view

     @param indexPath IndexPath to scroll to
     @param animated Toggle animations
     */
    - (void)scrollToIndexPathPreservingLeftInset:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        CGFloat sectionLeftInset = layout.sectionInset.left;
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attri = [layout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(attri.frame.origin.x - sectionLeftInset, 0) animated:animated];
    }
```

Swift (not verified syntactically)

```
func scroll(toIndexPathPreservingLeftInset indexPath: IndexPath, animated: Bool) {
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let sectionLeftInset = layout.sectionInset.left
    var attri = layout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: aPath)
    collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: (attri?.frame.origin.x - sectionLeftInset), y: 0), animated: animated)
}
```

[Sample gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWNOK.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

Set conentInset value to your collectionView like this:

```
myCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
```

and then add this line:

```
 if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            self.myCollectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior =     .never
        }
```

then  `scrolltoItem` works by respecting the insets of collectionView.

Comment: This is the up-to-date correct answer (tested on iOS 13). Prior to iOS 11 `collectionView.scrollToItem()` was respecting the collectionview insets, but on iOS 11 and above, we need to set `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Answer (score 2):

Since each cell's frame takes into account its section inset, you may as well use scrollRectToVisible(_:animated:).

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(cell.frame, animated: true)
```

And since it is a frame we're working on, you can fine tune some desired offset to that frame.

Comment: I thought this would work, but it's not doesn't anything at all in my case. I believe it because it needs contentSize set but I'm using itemSize.

Comment: cellForItem requires that the cell be visible, so won't work if you want to scroll to an index path that isn't visible.

Comment: In iOS 15+, this would work since cellForItem returns non-visible cells. Pre iOS-15, non visible cells would return nil.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles on this looking to scroll to the beginning of a horizontal collection view, **while considering the section insets**, I was able to get this to work by doing the following (in Swift 5.2.4). This solution takes advantage of the fact that UICollectionViews are UIScrollViews:

```
    (collectionView as UIScrollView).setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```